# I don't know how to use data from fetch api

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, api

I have less than one year of javascript experience.
I always have big trouble of how to use data from api.

for example, If I fetch products api something like that,

my console would show me `[{name:'pen',price:4},{name:'jeans',price:5}]`

okay and then if I want to add all the price from products, or I want to use the data to do something. 
so I use something `array.push(data)`

but it doesn't work and also it seems like super jerk.

so I would like to ask you guys what is the best way of handle this?

```
var array=[] 
async function getData() { 
    let response = await fetch('products/api');
    let data = await response.json() 
    return data;
}

getData().then(data =>console.log(data))
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sentinel , well I want to use reduce function to add all the price of the products.

Comment: @Sentinel so I need to make a data as an array.

Comment: if you object looks like your console is printing it:
`[{name:'pen',price:4},{name:'jeans',price:5}]`
then it is already an array

Comment: @Sentinel yes but that only works inside of fuction. if I do console.log(data) outside of fuction it doesnt work

Comment: do you mean the `then()`function when you say inside the function it works?

Comment: @Sentinel it doesn't work cuz await getdata() is outside of async function

Comment: could you please provide your whole code? also please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data comes in the form that you provided:

`[{name:'pen',price:4},{name:'jeans',price:5}]`

Which already is an array, you could do the following to sum up the prices:

```
async function getData() { 
    let response = await fetch('products/api');
    let data = await response.json() 
    return data;
}

var array = await getData();
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.price;

console.log(array.reduce(reducer, 0));
```

Which should print 14. Please note in order to use await you must be inside an async function. If you want to use then() you would do the following:

```
var array = [];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.price;

getData().then(data => {
    array = data;
    console.log(array.reduce(reducer, 0));
});
```

If you wanted to do more with the data you would have to do it inside the then() function.

Take a look at [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for the reduce function:

Comment: cool!! thanks buddy!

Comment: You are welcome. But you should checkout promises and await/async. The reason you didn't have any data outside of then is because it was asynchronous. So in order to better understand this you should research those things.

Comment: `await` works only inside async functions

Comment: @husanu yes you are correct, I changed the answer. If you find any mistakes or would write it differently please feel free to edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Of course you could also write an answer aswell :)

Comment: @Sentinel it was super helpful!! thank you soo much